# How do I fix startup delays in chef-solo

Tags: performance, chef-infra, chef-solo

Using chef solo, calling it directly - with logging set as high as possible, this is what I see in a tail:

```
[2015-03-24T12:21:48+11:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2015-03-24T12:21:48+11:00] DEBUG: Fork successful. Waiting for new chef pid: 5571
[2015-03-24T12:21:48+11:00] DEBUG: Forked instance now converging
[2015-03-24T12:21:49+11:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.8.2 ***
[2015-03-24T12:21:49+11:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 5571
[2015-03-24T12:25:41+11:00] DEBUG: Building node object for localhost.localdomain
...
```

and then it continues and goes on to work perfectly.  Notice in between the last two lines, there is a delay which varies between **3 and 5 minutes**!    With no explanation of what it's doing, nothing obvious on netstat or top - I'm at a loss for how to troubleshoot this.

I thought it might be a proxy thing, but setting the correct proxies in /etc/chef/client.rb changed nothing.     Any ideas how I get rid of this delay?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that Chef does when it starts - whether it's `chef-solo` or `chef-client`, is profile the system with `ohai`.

A main difference between `chef-solo` and `chef-client` is that debug log level will show the ohai output with `chef-client`, but it does not with `chef-solo`.

Depending on your system's configuration, this can take a long time to do, as it runs through a plethora of plugins. In particular, if you have a Linux system that is connected to Active Directory, it can take awhile to retrieve the user/group records via AD, which is why Ohai supports [disabling plugins](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html). Also, if you're running Chef and Ohai on a Windows system, it can take a long time.

To disable plugins, you need to edit the appropriate application's configuration file.

- chef-solo uses /etc/chef/solo.rb by default
- chef-client uses /etc/chef/client.rb by default

Add the following line to the appropriate config:

```
Ohai::Config[:disabled_plugins] = [:Passwd]
```

to disable the user/group lookup that might use Active Directory.

Also, I see from the output that you're using Chef 11.8.2 which came out  December 3, 2013 (over a year ago as of this answer). It's possible that a performance improvement was introduced since then.

However, if you're not specifically beholden to `chef-solo`, you might try using `chef-client` with local mode. There is more information about how to switch in [a blog post by Julian Dunn on Chef's site](https://www.chef.io/blog/2014/06/24/from-solo-to-zero-migrating-to-chef-client-local-mode/). If you need further assistance I strongly suggest the Chef irc channel on irc.freenode.net, or the [chef mailing list](http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/info/chef).

Comment: thanks - you've given me a lot of directions to look - really appreciate it!

Comment: ok - that's definitely the problem (active directory) - as you suggested, I ran chef-client -z instead of chef-solo, and passwd is the offending plugin.   However, putting something in /etc/chef/solo.rb and client.rb didn't work.  I was able to completely remove the problem by going into the gems directory and deleting passwd.rb.  I've googled and found people can't do it with a "generated solo.rb" - but haven't found any solutions :(  - but thanks, at least I have _A_ solution, even if it is evil

Comment: I solved this issue by disabling `:Uptime` plugin as described in answer.